# How to set layout params to units dp android

Tags: android

```
mainLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
mChart = new HorizontalBarChart(this);
mChart.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
mainLayout.addView(mChart);
```

I like to change the width and height to dp units like 100 dp or 200 dp,. the setLayoutParams doesn't take number units , the choices are only (wrap_content and match_content).. I'm new to Android so im confused how to change it.

Comment: `float px = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp, resources.getDisplayMetrics());` this way you can convert dp to pixels

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set Layoutparams height/width in dp value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41659338/how-to-set-layoutparams-height-width-in-dp-value)

Answer (score 18):

Another ways is you add your dimension in dimens.xml.

For example, add `<dimen name="chart_width">100dp</dimen>`.

Then, at your code:

```
float width = getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.chart_width);
mChart.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
            width,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Comment: `layoutParams.width` expects and `int` so you may need to cast the `getResources...` with `(int)`.

Answer (score 9):

Converting dip values into pixels will let your layout build correctly, this line of code will solve it:

```
int width = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(
    TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 
    getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.desired_width), 
    getResources().getDisplayMetrics()
);
```

Answer (score 3):

I think we can't set `dp` directly to the view. So we've to convert the dimension from `pixel` to `dp`.

To get `pixel` from `dp`, you can use `TypedValue#applyDimension()` method.

```
Resources r = getResources();
float px = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, {sizeInDp}, r.getDisplayMetrics());
```

So the final code will be

```
float width = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, {widthInDp}, r.getDisplayMetrics());

float height = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, {heightInDp}, r.getDisplayMetrics());

mChart.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                width,
                height));
```

Comment: where can i set the width to 100 dp for example?

Comment: `float width = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 100, r.getDisplayMetrics());` and apply `mChart.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                width,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));` , got it ?

Comment: @AxeFox, You answer also correct but I think little bit misleading. {widthInPixel} should change {withInDP} because it convert from DP to pixels. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @JoeyChong You're absolutely correct, I didn't noticed that mistake. I'll correct it now. and thank you for the correction Joey. :)

Comment: Worked like a charm! Enormous help by this! Thanks a lot theapache64!

Answer (score 0):

```
int dp1 = dip2pix(getContext(), 1);
FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            dp1 * 100, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

public static int dip2pix(@NonNull Context context, int dip) {
    return (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dip,
            context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Give it a try it will work for sure

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                200, 200);
        params.setMargins(5, 0, 5, 0);

        mChart= new HorizontalBarChart(getApplicationContext());
        mChart.setLayoutParams(params);

        mainLayout.addView(mChart);
```