# How to set Layoutparams height/width in dp value?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-adapter

I tried setting height/width manually in button but it didn't work. Then implemented Layoutparams. But size shows small and not getting required dp value.

**XML**

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/itemButton"
    android:layout_width="88dp"
    android:layout_height="88dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:background="#5e5789"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text=""
    android:textColor="#FFF"
    android:textSize="10sp" />
```

**Constructor:**

```
  public Item (int id, String name, String backgroundColor, String textColor, int width, int height){
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
    this.textColor = textColor;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;

}
```

**Adapter:**

```
@Override public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final Item item = items.get(position);
    holder.itemView.setTag(item);
    holder.itemButton.setText(item.getName());
    holder.itemButton.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(item.getTextColor()));
    holder.itemButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(item.getBackgroundColor()));
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = holder.itemButton.getLayoutParams();
    params.width = item.getWidth();
    params.height = item.getHeight();
    holder.itemButton.setLayoutParams(params);

}
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

When you specify values programmatically in the `LayoutParams`, those values are expected to be pixels.

To convert between pixels and dp you have to multiply by the current density factor. That value is in the `DisplayMetrics`, that you can access from a `Context`:

```
float pixels =  dp * context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
```

So in your case you could do:

```
.
.
float factor = holder.itemView.getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
params.width = (int)(item.getWidth() * factor);
params.height = (int)(item.getHeight() * factor);
.
.
```

Comment: Your explanation is very clear and precise! Thanks man! It worked!

Comment: did not work for me... Calculations are off on different devices ..

Answer (score 7):

Option 1: Use dimens.xml

```kotlin
view.updateLayoutParams {
    width = resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.my_width)
    height = resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.my_height)
}
```

Option 2: Dispense with dimens.xml

```kotlin
/** Converts dp to pixel. */
val Int.px get() = (this * Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.density).toInt()
```

```kotlin
view.updateLayoutParams {
    width = 100.px
    height = 100.px
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I believe you should be using a *dp value* defined in *dimens* along with [getDimensionPixelSize](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources#getDimensionPixelSize(int)). In a custom view, the Kotlin implementation would look like:

```
val layoutParams = layoutParams
val width = context.resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.width_in_dp)
layoutParams.width = width
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = ListView.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = (int) (50 * customsDebts.size() * (getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density));
        params.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        ListView.setLayoutParams(params);
```